# Acknowledgement from RabbitMQ

Tags: ios, rabbitmq, rabbitmq-c

After publishing message on RabbitMQ like that :

```
[exchange publishMessage:@"YOUR MESSAGE" usingRoutingKey:routingQueue propertiesMessage:props mandatory:NO immediate:NO error:&error];
```

It works perfectly but is it possible to receive the acknowledgement from RabbitMQ for each message with this lib ?

https://github.com/profmaad/librabbitmq-objc

Comment: Who do you mean to ` receive the acknowledgement from RabbitMQ` ?  The publisher?

Comment: I just need the validation that the message has been received with success

Comment: Ok, again - by whom is the validation needed? Do you want that confirmation from consumer to broker or broker to publisher?

Comment: broker to publisher, please

Answer (score 0):

So these [publisher acknowledgments](http://www.rabbitmq.com/confirms.html) (since you wrote in the comment you are interested in broker->publisher) are on the amqp level, handled by RMQ itself. In the "API" level you may get a exception or a return value or some indication  depends on the library.

Quote from the aforementioned link:

> For unroutable messages, the broker will issue a confirm once the
>   exchange verifies a message won't route to any queue (returns an empty
>   list of queues). If the message is also published as mandatory, the
>   basic.return is sent to the client before basic.ack. The same is true
>   for negative acknowledgements (basic.nack).
>
> For routable messages, the basic.ack is sent when a message has been
>   accepted by all the queues. For persistent messages routed to durable
>   queues, this means persisting to disk. For mirrored queues, this means
>   that all mirrors have accepted the message.